# Use str.split() to set value of column in dataframe, but only for some rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like e.g.:

```
id some_string  
1. blah,count=1,blah
2. blah,blah
3  blah,count=4,blah
4. blah,blah
5  blah,count=4,blah
6. blah,count=3,blah
```

I would like to use split to set a separate column with the value of count to get:

```
id some_string        count
1  blah,count=1,blah   1
2  blah,blah           0
3  blah,count=4,blah   4
4  blah,blah           0 
5  blah,count=4,blah   4
6  blah,count=3,blah   3
```

I tried:

```
df['count'].str.split('[count=|,]',expand=True)[3]
```

but it rightly complains that:

```
 Length of values (4) does not match length of index (6)
```

Is there an obvious way of doing this short of looping through the dataframe entries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't `split`, use [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['count'] = (df['some_string'].str.extract(r'count=(\d+)', expand=False)
               .fillna(0).astype(int)
              )
```

Output:

```
    id        some_string  count
0  1.0  blah,count=1,blah      1
1  2.0          blah,blah      0
2  3.0  blah,count=4,blah      4
3  4.0          blah,blah      0
4  5.0  blah,count=4,blah      4
5  6.0  blah,count=3,blah      3
```

Regex:

```
count=    # match literal "count="
(         # start capturing group
\d+       # capture one or more (+) digits (\d)
)         # end capturing group
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6n0CEx/1)

Comment: Can you explain what this means/how it works: r'count=(\d+)' please?

Comment: @abinitio this means find the string `count=` and if there is one or more digits `\d+` after it, capture them `(…)`. I'll add a note in my answer

Answer (score 5):

*(@mozway answered faster than me, it is normal to accept his answer rather than mine)*

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['count'] = df['some_string'].str.extract('count=(\d+)').fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)

# Output
   id        some_string count
0   1  blah,count=1,blah     1
1   2          blah,blah     0
2   3  blah,count=4,blah     4
3   4          blah,blah     0
4   5  blah,count=4,blah     4
5   6  blah,count=3,blah     3
```